# Why is it prohibited to eat porc?

Tags: halal-haram, food

salam,

I was with friends and one of them (not muslim) asked me : why, you muslims, do not eat porc ? Did you question yourself..Etc

Well, I heard about some scientific research saying that the porc meat/fat contains some microscopic thigs that are not good for health, but I was not sure, plus science is so not "stable" thing, today something is good for health, tomorrow it's the worst thing ever..

So I didn't want to speak about what I do not know/master. I just said, sometime I do not ask questions, and I do not have enough knowledge, so I prefer to avoid to eat it till the day I will know why.

So WHY ? why we do not eat porc, is it a clear verse in quran that explains why ? is there a known reason ?

Thank you

Comment: We don't eat pork because Allah forbids us. Even if pork had zero detriments and a thousand proven benefits we would still not eat it. That is the simple answer.

Comment: here are the reasons for WHY we do not eat pork (2:173), (6:145) and (16:115). when Allah azzawajjal prohibits something with a clear command, we do not ask why